# Python Bokeh Not Changing the Colour of the Text when Updating

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to update the colour of a text on a plot I am creating.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```py
plot = figure(
  x_axis_location="above", tools="hover,save",
  x_range=list(reversed(names)), y_range=names,
  tooltips = [('names', '@yname, @xname'), ('count', '@count')]
)

plot.width = 4500
plot.height = 4500
plot.grid.grid_line_color = 'pink'
plot.axis.axis_line_color = 'pink'
plot.axis.major_tick_line_color = 'white'
plot.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
plot.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "22px"
plot.axis.major_label_standoff = 3
plot.xaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/2

plot.rect('xname', 'yname', 1.0, 1.0, source=data,
          color='colors', alpha='alphas', line_color=None,
          hover_line_color='pink', hover_color='colors'
          )

save(plot, title='plot.html', filename="plot.html")
```

According to the documentation it should be pretty simple:

```py
plot.axis.axis_label_text_color = 'white'
```

However, Bokeh refuses to change the color of any of the axis texts. I'm pretty befuddled on how to get the axis labels to be white or what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

```py
        plot.xaxis.axis_label_text_color = 'white'         
        plot.yaxis.major_label_text_color = 'white'
```

It's this. The documentation for this is funky.